# How to move to other Jpanel inside class that extend JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I want to move to other JPanel inside class that extend JPanel.
I want to move from First Panel to Second Panel. My question : **I want to go to class SecondPanel inside secondPanelButtonActionPerformed method**

**MainMenu.java**

```
public class MainMenu extends JFrame {

    public MainMenu() {
       FirstPanel firstPanel = new FirstPanel();
       this.setSize(500,500);
       this.add(firstPanel);
       this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainMenu().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**FirstPanel.java**

```
public class FirstPanel extends JPanel {
    private void secondPanelButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    }
}
```

**SecondPanel.java**

```
public class SecondPanel extends JPanel {

}
```

Comment: *"I want.."*  OK.  That's a specification, but what is your question?  BTW - look at `CardLayout` - it allows us to 'flip' between different panels.

Comment: I don't want to use CardLayout just JPanel because my college task deadline is now. I want to go to class SecondPanel inside secondPanelButtonActionPerformed method

Comment: *"..because my college task deadline is now.."*  a) It will be quicker to do with `CardLayout` b) You should plan your time better than to need to mention your own time constraints to strangers on the internet (who really don't care).

Comment: OK, thanks for the advice